# How do i Remove text in between and around other text in notepad++

Tags: text, notepad++

I need to clear text around other text... example:text = hello there sir how are you doing

Tex to be removed = hello sir are doing

Result = there how you

What would i put in to skip all other text but the words in the text to be removed with the ctrl h menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a regex based search and replace:

**Find what**: `\S+(?:\s+(\S+))?`
**Replace with**: `$1`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hiR28J/3)

**Details**:

- `\S+`  - one or more chars other than whitespace
- `(?:\s+(\S+))?` - one or zero occurrences of

  - `\s+`  - 1+ whitespaces
  - `(\S+)`  - Group 1: one or more chars other than whitespace

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do find/replace with regexes in Notepad++.